# how to send a String data from Main-activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have a web-view in a fragment. I want to load the webview by selecting a url from the main activity. For example my webview is loading the url http://google.com/ ,which is from (url) my main activity. In other words, I have a string like below in my main activity , I want to use it to load my web-view which is in the fragment , how can I do that? 
Please help me to solve this problem

`String url="http://google.com/";`

Comment: is that string is hard coded variable like as you said String url="http://google.com/"; in your mainactivity

Comment: use interface that you used to send url from fragment to activity.

Comment: i don't understand what did you meant by  hard coded variable, what ever i want to load a url (any) in my fragment from main activity@FaisalAhmed

Comment: I am a bigger so can u give me an example ?@DivyeshPatel

Comment: post your activity and fragment class

Comment: see the last example in this site https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: its a huge code, dude@FerdousAhamed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to send data to fragment from activity

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("url", "http://google.com/");
  //set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then recieve in fragment's onCreateView method

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          String strtext=getArguments().getString("url");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: can i use url by using this to load webview ?

Comment: You only have to pass the url as a string to fragment , and then in fragment simply use that string to load URL

Comment: Yes you can use this "url" in fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by two ways.

1) By making the setter method for url.

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
   private String url;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 }

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return rootView;
 }
 public void setUrl(String url){
    this.url = url;

 }
}
```

Call that methord before adding fragment:

```
 WebViewFragment fragment = new WebViewFragment();
      fragment.setUrl(url);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
.replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
```

2) You can use that bu intent bundle

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("url", "www.google.com");

   Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Parse it in fragment:

public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
       private String url;

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 }

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  url = getArguments().getString("url");
    return rootView;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Fragment homeFragment = new LotteryDetailFragment();
            FragmentTransaction homeTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            String str = "you string";
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("param_str", str);
            homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            homeTransaction.addToBackStack("HomeFragment");
                     homeTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, homeFragment, "HomeFragment");
            homeTransaction.commit();
```

in on onCreateView of destination fragment

```
  String str=getArguments().getString("param_str");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1 - From Activity :

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("url", "www.google.com");

    Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

2 - In Fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    this.activity = getActivity();
    String url = getArguments().getString("url");
    return layoutView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

**Send data from Activity**

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("url", "http://www.google.com");
MyFragment frg = new MyFragment();
frg.setArguments(data);
```

**Receive data in Fragment**

```
String url = getArguments().getString("url");
```

Comment: 05-04 19:22:35.719 23585-23585/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
05-04 19:22:35.723 23585-23585/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.